# JQuery UI Validation not showing Grails?

Tags: jquery, grails, user-interface, validation

I have been working on a Grails application and have recently wanted to add client-side validation using JQuery UI Validation Plug-in. I followed these steps to do so:

1. ran this command: **grails install-plugin jquery-validation-ui**
2. Added this to the view: `<r:require modules="jquery-validate, jquery-ui" />`
3. I also tried this: `<r:require modules="jquery-validation-ui" />`

I have also inspected the view once running and can see that the required JavaScript files have been attached to the view using the resources tag, however the errors are not showing which seems weird because if I add this code to the view it works:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${modelInstance}">
    <div class="alert error">
        <g:renderErrors bean="${modelInstance}" as="list" />
    </div>
</g:hasErrors>
```

Below is the code added by the plug-in to **config**:

```
// Added by the JQuery Validation UI plugin:
jqueryValidationUi {
    errorClass = 'error'
    validClass = 'valid'
    onsubmit = true
    renderErrorsOnTop = false

    qTip {
        packed = true
      classes = 'ui-tooltip-red ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'  
    }

    /*
      Grails constraints to JQuery Validation rules mapping for client side validation.
      Constraint not found in the ConstraintsMap will trigger remote AJAX validation.
    */
    StringConstraintsMap = [
        blank:'required', // inverse: blank=false, required=true
        creditCard:'creditcard',
        email:'email',
        inList:'inList',
        minSize:'minlength',
        maxSize:'maxlength',
        size:'rangelength',
        matches:'matches',
        notEqual:'notEqual',
        url:'url',
        nullable:'required',
        unique:'unique',
        validator:'validator'
    ]

    // Long, Integer, Short, Float, Double, BigInteger, BigDecimal
    NumberConstraintsMap = [
        min:'min',
        max:'max',
        range:'range',
        notEqual:'notEqual',
        nullable:'required',
        inList:'inList',
        unique:'unique',
        validator:'validator'
    ]

    CollectionConstraintsMap = [
        minSize:'minlength',
        maxSize:'maxlength',
        size:'rangelength',
        nullable:'required',
        validator:'validator'
    ]

    DateConstraintsMap = [
        min:'minDate',
        max:'maxDate',
        range:'rangeDate',
        notEqual:'notEqual',
        nullable:'required',
        inList:'inList',
        unique:'unique',
        validator:'validator'
    ]

    ObjectConstraintsMap = [
        nullable:'required',
        validator:'validator'
    ]

    CustomConstraintsMap = [
        phone:'true', // International phone number validation
        phoneUS:'true',
        alphanumeric:'true',
        letterswithbasicpunc:'true',
    lettersonly:'true'
    ]   
}
```

Can someone please advise if there are some addition steps that need taking in order to validate on the client-side? I have also included a sample of one of the text boxes I want to validate:

```
<tr class="prop">
            <td valign="top" class="name">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <g:textField id="name" name='name' bean="${modelInstance}" value="${name}"
                           size='40'/>
            </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you load or submit your page, appears some javascript error in your browser console?

Comment: Tell a lie, I just re-checked and there is this error for some reason: TypeError: $(".date").datepicker is not a function 
$(".date").datepicker();

Comment: anyone able to help on this? Thanks

Comment: check the import of query ui and check if the order is correct (maybe ui before jquery?)

Comment: Did you ever fix this ? Having the same weird issue, no errors from firebug console, select submit no errors are shown :/